# ASP.Net MVC CMS with Rest API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

I'm looking for recommendations for a ASP.Net MVC based Content Management System (CMS).  My needs are to have a stand-alone admin site where content contributors can manage content.  They should be able to tag their content with what site(s) and page(s) the content is made available to.  I also need to access the data via a RESTful API where I can pull content into a page for a site programmatically.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: SO is not a reccomendation engine. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/) and [Umbarco](http://umbraco.com/) are some of the most popular ASP.NET MVC CMS. Make sure you have checked them to see if they suit your needs.